# Remove part of string that contains a tag

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in JavaScript that holds the below value:

```
<label>AAA</label>
```

I need just the AAA. I try to replace the characters but it is failing. Would someone please suggest the best approach?

```
var company="<label>AAA</label>";// I am getting this value from element
var rx = new RegExp("((\\$|)(([1-9]\\d{0,2}(\\,\\d{3})*|([1-9]\\d*))(\\.\\d{2})))|(\\<)*(\\>)");
var arr = rx.exec(company);
var arr1 = company.match(rx);
if (arr[1] != null) {
    var co = arr[1].replace(",", "");
       }
```

}

Comment: _I try to replace the characters but it is failing_.. Where it fails?

Comment: Please show us the code you are using to replace the characters.

Comment: Consider `var x="AAA"` instead of `var x="<label>AAA</label>"` but then again your code might be more complex.

Comment: here is the code I am trying to use, I am highly doubtful if I am correct:

Comment: var company="<label>AAA</label>";// I am getting this value from element
    var rx = new RegExp("((\\$|)(([1-9]\\d{0,2}(\\,\\d{3})*|([1-9]\\d*))(\\.\\d{2})))|(\\<)*(\\>)");
    var arr = rx.exec(company);
    var arr1 = company.match(rx);
    if (arr[1] != null) {
        var co = arr[1].replace(",", "");
           }
}

Answer (score 1):

As you say you need only `AAA`, consider the below code.

I have taken a substring between the first `'>'` character in the string company, added 1 to that and the last `<` character. However, if the company var contains more of such `<` or `>`, you could go for a regex approach.

```js
var company="<label>AAA</label>";

alert(company.substring(company.indexOf('>')+1, company.lastIndexOf('<')));
```

Comment: @Sim You are welcome.. Learning is good :) Do accept the answer if it helped you find the solution :)